# Шаблоны функций

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Нужно поменять местами наибольший элемент массива с первым, а наименьший с последним.
Почему-то не меняет, подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.
Вот код:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    vector<T> original;
    int size;
public:

    A();
    A(int size);
    void Input();
    void Output();
    void Max();
    void Min();




};
template <typename T>
A<T>::A()
{
    size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
A<T>::A(int size)
{

    this->size = size;

}
template <typename T>
void A<T>::Input()
{
    T tmp;
    if (size != 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter elements" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cin >> tmp;
            original.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
}


template <typename T>
void A<T>::Output()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout<< original[i] <<" ";
}

template <typename T>
void A<T>::Max()
{
    T max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (original[i] > max) {
            max = original[i];
            swap(max, original[0]);
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void A<T>::Min()
{
    T min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (original[i] < min) {
            original[i]=min;
            swap(original[5], min);
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    A<int> ch(6);
    ch.Input();
    ch.Output();
    cout << endl;
    ch.Max();
    ch.Min();
    ch.Output();
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
template <typename T>
void A<T>::Max()
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (original[i] > original[max])
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    swap(original[max], original[0]);
}

template <typename T>
void A<T>::Min()
{
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (original[i] < original[min]) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    swap(original[size-1], original[min]);
}
```